# Android too much work in main thread

Tags: android, android-activity, methods

I'm new to Android, and I'm building an application with 5 buttons where each button play a diffrent song. I've built the code wich is running OK, but the activity takes up to 2seconds to open and I'm getting an "skipped 104 frames" warning in LogCat. All my code goes in onCreate method, and I think this is why it takes this long to open. How can I create a new method and how can I have the same functionality? Can you please provide an example? 
My code:

```
package com.example.testapplication;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.media.MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class SoundActivity extends Activity {

 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);setContentView(R.layout.activity_sound);
        setRequestedOrientation (ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT); 
            getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);  

   //SONGS
    final MediaPlayer song1 = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.drawable.song1);
    final MediaPlayer song2 = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.drawable.song2);

  //BUTTONS
    Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    Button button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);

 //CHECKBOX
    final CheckBox loop = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.loop);


  button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
              if(loop.isChecked()) {   //CHECKBOX
                    song1.setLooping(true);
                }
              if(song2.isPlaying()) {
                 song2.pause();
                 song1.start(); 
              }  
             song1.start();
        }
    }); 
 /* EDITED 
  button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
              if(loop.isChecked()) {   //CHECKBOX
                    song2.setLooping(true);
                }
              if(song1.isPlaying()) {
                 song1.pause();
                 song2.start(); 
              }  

             song2.start();
        }
    }); 
                */EDITED
}//onCreate
} //soundActivity class
```

I need that if song2 is playing when I press the song1 button to stop them and to play just song1. And so on on every Button, but it takes up to 5 if instructions. Any other way to do it?
I'm starting my SoundActivity from MainActivity, here's the code:

```
package com.example.testapplication;
import com.example.testapplication.R;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
                setRequestedOrientation (ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT); 
                getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);     

             TextView button01 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.button01); 
             button01.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {        
                     startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SoundActivity.class));
                }
             }); 
}   
}
```

EDIT: SOLVED - I've created a new thread in the onStart() method. The code works just fine and the activity takes around 140ms to open. Thank you for your answers.

Comment: There is nothing in your code that takes time. The code in onClick is not executed at the moment the activity is created so we don't have to look at that. There must be something else.

Comment: Well, here's my entire code. Then what's slowing down the application? It takes up to 2-3 seconds to open the activity.

Comment: Think that the two media player lines are the culprit. Take them out to test.

Comment: I've took them out, but it's just the same. Can you tell me where the thread sample code needs to go (in onCreate method or another one)? Thank you!

Comment: For me you don't have to add thread code. You should first find out what is time consuming? Is this your main activity? If not, how to you start it? You did not post the whole activity as there is nothing that could take time exept for the media players? For example where do you set your layout? setContentView is missing.

Comment: Sorry, I messed arround with the codeblock element on stackoverflow, my mistake. The SoundActivity is started from the MainActivity.

Comment: The MainActivity loads instantly but when I click on the button to open SoundActivity it takes up like 2-3 seconds to open it.

Comment: You have special views in your xml layout that could take time? Too big jpg files for background?

Comment: I have just 2 linear layouts, 2 buttons, 2 textviews, and one checkbox. I'm not using any jpg files for background, just a background color.

Comment: Very, very strange. Don't you have to set the full screen flag before set content view?

Comment: I tried to surround a part of my java code inside a comment, and the activity opens quickly so I think the problem is in java. I've set it before the content view right now, but still the same problem.

Comment: Which part. Please show.

Comment: I've edited my code, please take a look.

Comment: Ok. Now put one on click listener back in. Why new View.onClickListener instead of new onClickListener? After that comment the code in the onClicks out. I would be surprised...

Comment: Well, this is what I've got from several tutorials. Is this the problem?

Comment: I don't know but you can find out... There has something to be tried...

Comment: Alright, I'll try this out. Thank you for your help. I'll come back with an answer.

Comment: I changed to onClickListener and still the same, it has a latency of 2-3 seconds when opening the SoundActivity. Maybe a thread will do the trick?

Comment: You could .... extends Activity inplements onClickListener. And then override onClick. For what its worth...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as an example and a basic implementation

```
public class SoundActivity extends Activity {
private MediaPlayer mediasong1;
private MediaPlayer mediasong2;

 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   //SONGS
        new MediaLoaderTask().execute();

  //BUTTONS
    Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    Button button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);

  //onClick
  button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
              if(loop.isChecked()) {   //CHECKBOX
                    song1.setLooping(true);
                }
              if(song2.isPlaying()) {
                 song2.pause();
                 song1.start(); 
              }  
             song1.start();
        }
    }); 

  button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
              if(loop.isChecked()) {   //CHECKBOX
                    song2.setLooping(true);
                }
              if(song1.isPlaying()) {
                 song1.pause();
                 song2.start(); 
              }  

             song2.start();
        }
    }); 
}
 private class MediaLoaderTask extends
    android.os.AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
    mediasong1 = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(),
            R.drawable.song1);
    mediasong2 = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(),
            R.drawable.song2);
}

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using different threads! You're running everything on the main UI thread. You should look into:

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I know, that's my problem, can you give me an example, please?

Comment: Read the doc here, it has examples: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Answer (score 0):

You've to use Thread concept such that all these things just don't run on the main UI Thread but takes up another thread to run and keep your UI without issues for the user experience.

I would suggest you to use this sample code example but before implementing ensure to read this : which especially to overcome the issue or concerns you mentioned. It's time taking but definitely worth : 
[Processes and Threads](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html)

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
           //your code here;
        }
    }).start();
}
```

Comment: The statements in `onClick` are not the ones that make the `Activity` slow to start.  @greenapps' comment to the question is correct.

Comment: Yeah...I read your question and code once again...Why can't you post your entire code such that we can suggest you better way to handle the scenario ?

Comment: Where should I implement the sample code, in the onCreate method? Or I have to create a new one?